# How to run a python script inside the cgi-bin of apache server?

Tags: python, apache

I put a simple python script inside the cgi-bin in apache2 and tried to execute it using the browser as follows,

"http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/test.py"

But it gives a 500 Internal sever error.

Following is the error.log in apache2.

[Sun Jul 29 22:07:51 2012] [error] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.py' failed
[Sun Jul 29 22:07:51 2012] [error] [client ::1] Premature end of script headers: test.py
[Sun Jul 29 22:07:51 2012] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico

can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Well, if you gave your source code... >_>

Comment: Please stop shooting yourself in the foot, nobody does python for the web as CGI nowadays, you'll even be seen as the "weird" guy if you try to use mod_python for Apache. Please use a WSGI framework, there's many of them to choose from. Bottle, Flask or web.py can be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not sending the headers properly.

Try if this simplest example script runs:

```
print('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n')
print("Hello, World!")
```

Comment: No I sending that correctly as you said. But issue is same  . . . .

Answer (score 1):

BlaXpirit's answer should solve your problem with a 500 server internal error.

It is important to note the "\n" at the end of the first print statement.  You can also write it as

print("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8")

print()

I was surprised to learn that writing out these headers is necessary even if your Python program is only going to do server-side work - with no response to the browser at all.